# How do I turn off the tabindex in visual studio C# WFA?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tabindex

I am making this very simple app, which is kinda like flappy bird, but just much cooler.
So the basic idea is, you move up and Down with the arrow keys "Up" and "Down". But I have 3 buttons on the screen, while the game is running. The up and Down keys are conflicting with my tabindex on those buttons. I just can't seem to find any function that can remove the buttons from the tabindex list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: On the buttons, set Focusable and IsTabStop to false

Comment: TabStop only Works with "Tab" not with the arrow keys, so that won't Work.

Comment: My bad, I forgot I am working in a WFA and not a WPF, and WFA does not have Focusable

Comment: WFA == Windows Forms App?

Comment: Windows Forms Application yes